# netbeans glassfish hibernate log4j2

Tags: log4j2

I have a simple Netbeans 7.1.2 (NON MAVEN) project that use glassfish 3.1 server for testing.

I created a log4j2.xml file and placed it on the classpath 
here it is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="debug"/>
        <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} [%t] %-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="rolling-file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="c:\tmp\Program-Name.log"/>
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="500KB"/>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="4"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %l - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.hibernate">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <priority value ="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="rolling-file" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

the project uses hibernate to store data from a web service to a database.

However I am not able to log anything. I can see the logs of hibernate into the Netbeans IDE but I cannot see the created on the filesystem file.

I have this error when calling the web service

```
SEVERE: ERROR StatusLogger Unknown object "logger" of type org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig is ignored
SEVERE: ERROR StatusLogger root contains an invalid element or attribute "priority"
SEVERE: ERROR StatusLogger Unknown object "root" of type org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig is ignored
```

could someone pls help or give some advice I googled and stackoverflowed but without chance.

Paolo

Answer (score 3):

I think that your *log4j2.xml* file is mixed with the old log4j style xml.
I'm having the same trouble as you when it comes to appending hibernate log to my application's log file. But I think that I can help with the logger error.

Try this file instead (and note the changes that I made):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration name="SOME_PROJ_NAME" status="OFF">
    <appenders>
        <RollingFile name="rolling-file" fileName="c:/tmp/Program-Name.log" filePattern="c:/tmp/$${date:yyyy-MM}/Program-Name-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{ABSOLUTE} [%t] %-5p %c{1} - %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="6" modulate="true"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </appenders>
    <loggers>
        <root level="info"
            <appender-ref ref="rolling-file"/>
        </root>
        <logger name="org.hibernate level="info">
            <appender-ref ref="rolling-file"/>
        </logger>
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

It is quite similar to the one that I'm using. Note that this file should be on classpath for log4j2 auto configuration to kick in.
The most important thing you should do when using the net to configure log4j2 is that you're looking at **log4j2** and **not log4j** style configuration.
I suggest that you look in http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/ for further info. They have a good [downloadable pdf](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-users-guide.pdf) that you can check out.
In addition, check out [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526772/log4j2-auto-config) about a similar problem.